# I can't connect to a new TFS server because Visual Studio won't let me supply new credentials

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to connect to a new TFS server in Visual Studio 2015. I already have a local TFS server on my dev machine. When I attempt to add the new TFS server in the "Add Team Foundation Server" prompt it allows me to enter the URL, path and port number, but no credentials. Without credentials it can't connect to the server because it's supplying my local admin credentials instead of my active directory ID.

I've tried Credential Manager in Control Panel but it is empty. I've tried clearing my internet explorer cache/passwords/everything. I've tried running Visual Studio with the /netonly switch and supplied my AD credentials. None of this has worked.

How do I add a new TFS server to my list that I can connect to?

Comment: When you tried to connect to the new TFS, was there a windows promoted to let you enter credential? Did you check Web credentials or Windows Credentials in the Credential Manager?

Answer (score 0):

1. Close VS, and clean the cache file under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache`.
2. Check Windows Credentials in the Credential Manager to see if there stores credentials.
3. Remove the local TFS in Add/Remove Team Foundation Server.

After the steps above, when you connect new TFS, a windows should promote to let you enter credential.

Comment: The cache directory has a bunch of directories in it. The directory names are guids. Am I supposed to clear the entire cache directory, or just certain specific files?

Comment: I can't remove my local TFS as it contains my version history for the last 6 months.

Comment: All folders in cache directory can be cleaned. Remove TFS in VS won't delete anything in your local TFS, if you want to check your local TFS data , you can add the server in VS again and connect to it.